# Store data to array coming from XML file in ajax request

Tags: ajax, xml

I have one XML file from which I need to get data & store them in an array. Somehow array is not being created expectedly. I've used `each` function to loop through the xml file.
Here's my code:

**AJAX Request**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "products.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
         $(xml).find('Products').each(function(){
                var proid = $(this).find('ProductID').text();
                var proname = $(this).find('ProductName').text();
                var catid = $(this).find('CategoryID').text();
                var qua=$(this).find('QuantityPerUnit').text();
                var price=$(this).find('UnitPrice').text();
                var products = new Array();
                for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
                    products[i]=new Array();
                    products[i][0]= proid;
                    products[i][1]= proname;
                    products[i][2]= catid;
                    products[i][3]= qua;
                    products[i][4]= price;
                }
            });
        }
        alert(products[0][2]);  // Nothing happens
    });
```

**Sample of XML File**

```
<ProductsRoot>
<Products>
<ProductID>1</ProductID>
<ProductName>Chai</ProductName>
<CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
<QuantityPerUnit>10 boxes x 20 bags</QuantityPerUnit>
<UnitPrice>18</UnitPrice>
</Products>
</ProductsRoot>
```

When I loop through `each` function, I expect it to work like `for loop` but something's that I can not see. Can anyone spot the mistake? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "products.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {
    var products = new Array();
     $(xml).find('Products').each(function(){
            var proid = $(this).find('ProductID').text();
            var proname = $(this).find('ProductName').text();
            var catid = $(this).find('CategoryID').text();
            var qua=$(this).find('QuantityPerUnit').text();
            var price=$(this).find('UnitPrice').text();

            for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
                products[i]=new Array();
                products[i][0]= proid;
                products[i][1]= proname;
                products[i][2]= catid;
                products[i][3]= qua;
                products[i][4]= price;
            }
        });
        alert(products[0][2]);
    }

});
```

}